# Cannot close showDialog

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have an showDialog. After first showDialog loaded I am calling another showDialog from viewModel:

```
var connectionWindow = new ConnectionWindow();
connectionWindow.Closed += (o, args) =>
{
    if (connectionWindow.DialogResult.HasValue && connectionWindow.DialogResult.Value)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
};
connectionWindow.ShowDialog();
```

In the second show dialog I am trying to close it following way:

```
 public ConnectionWindow()
 {
     _viewModel = new ConnectionWindowViewModel();
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = _viewModel;
     _viewModel.ClosingRequest += () =>
                                  {
                                      DialogResult = true;
                                      Close();
                                  };
 }
```

When closingRequest happens, execution breaks on the line

> DialogResult = true;

There are no mistake or anything else in VS, but it does not close second showDialog window. Any ideas of how can I close second dialog?

**Edit**
I want to close second showDialog by clicking the button. Here is xaml code of my button:

```
<Button Content="Save Connection" Width="108" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding OnSaveConnectionCommand}">
```

**Edit2**
The problem was in firing OnClosingRequest from task:

```
private void OnSaveConnection(object sender)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                          {
                              if (IsServerConnected(_entityBuilder.ToString()))
                              {
                                   OnClosingRequest();      
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  MessageBox.Show("Cannot establish connection with server " , Properties.Resources.Error, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                              }
                          }).ContinueWith(_ => {Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;}, uiScheduler);
    }
```

When I moved OnClosingRequest(); to ContinueWith, everything started to work.

Comment: You need to use Show instead of ShowDialog to make several windows active at the same time.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call Close method of already closing dialog.

Comment: @BogdanVerbenets ClosingRequest is an event from viewModel to close showDialog

Comment: @Alex But I don't want user to have access to first window, while second is open. But I try your suggestion

Comment: Anything in that Closed event handler that could be blocking? You can just execute that code after the call to ShowDialog(). That is blocking for sure.

Comment: ok I think I found where is a problem. Thank you for pointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with firing OnClosingRequest from task:

```
private void OnSaveConnection(object sender)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                          {
                              if (IsServerConnected(_entityBuilder.ToString()))
                              {
                                   OnClosingRequest();      
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  MessageBox.Show("Cannot establish connection with server " , Properties.Resources.Error, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                              }
                          }).ContinueWith(_ => {Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;}, uiScheduler);
    }
```